# Process sometimes fails to run anything in Main method and unloads app domain

Tags: c#, mono, gdb, clr, cil

I have two C# applications with user interfaces running on Mono 4.0.3 and OpenSUSE 13.1. The first application launches the second and then waits for it to exit. Sometimes (say 1 in 10 times) the second application "fails" to load - the process will start, but sit at 0% processor time. If I place a Console.WriteLine at the very start of the Main method, that WriteLine never happens.

I launch the process very simply:

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("mono", " --gc=boehm MyProgram.exe");
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
var process = Process.Start(psi);
```

Following the steps for [debugging Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/debug+profile/debug/), the mono_backtrace output from gdb is:

```
#0  0x00007f4dbc966c1b in sigsuspend () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000000000615941 in GC_suspend_handler ()
#2  <signal handler called>
#3  0x00007f4dbcf030ad in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#4  0x00000000005df2d3 in _wapi_handle_timedwait_signal_handle ()
#5  0x00000000005f26fb in wapi_WaitForSingleObjectEx ()
#6  0x00000000005a9062 in mono_domain_try_unload ()
#7  0x00000000005a9154 in mono_domain_unload ()
#8 0x401931d2 in  (wrapper managed-to-native) System.AppDomain:InternalUnload (int) + 0x52 (0x40193180 0x401931fe) [0x7f4dbd9c0d48 - MyProgram.exe]
#9  0x00007f4daa37d370 in ?? ()
#10 0x00007f4daa37d370 in ?? ()
#11 0x00007f4daa37d370 in ?? ()
#12 0x0000000001f17068 in ?? ()
#13 0x00007f4daa359af0 in ?? ()
#14 0x0000000001abb1d0 in ?? ()
#15 0x40192dd4 in <0x40192dd4 - JIT trampoline for System.AppDomain:InternalUnload (int)>
#16 0x00007fff4c7a9fe0 in ?? ()
#17 0x00007fff4c7a9ed0 in ?? ()
#18 0x40192da8 in  System.AppDomain:Unload (System.AppDomain) + 0x28 (0x40192d80 0x40192dd4) [0x7f4dbd9c0d48 - MyProgram.exe]
```

I'm not sure what is going on here and my Googling has proved fruitless. Any ideas?

Edit: in response to comment from @EmployedRussian, here's the output from `thread apply all where`:

```
Thread 10 (Thread 0x7f4dbc0f7700 (LWP 7994)):
#0  0x00007f4dbcf030af in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000000000615823 in GC_wait_marker ()
#2  0x000000000060dad5 in GC_help_marker ()
#3  0x0000000000613f87 in GC_mark_thread ()
#4  0x00007f4dbceff0db in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00007f4dbca1890d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6

Thread 9 (Thread 0x7f4dbb8f6700 (LWP 7995)):
#0  0x00007f4dbcf030af in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000000000615823 in GC_wait_marker ()
#2  0x000000000060dad5 in GC_help_marker ()
#3  0x0000000000613f87 in GC_mark_thread ()
#4  0x00007f4dbceff0db in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00007f4dbca1890d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6

Thread 8 (Thread 0x7f4dbb0f5700 (LWP 7996)):
#0  0x00007f4dbcf030af in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000000000615823 in GC_wait_marker ()
#2  0x000000000060dad5 in GC_help_marker ()
#3  0x0000000000613f87 in GC_mark_thread ()
#4  0x00007f4dbceff0db in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00007f4dbca1890d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6

Thread 7 (Thread 0x7f4dba8f4700 (LWP 7997)):
#0  0x00007f4dbcf030af in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000000000615823 in GC_wait_marker ()
#2  0x000000000060dad5 in GC_help_marker ()
#3  0x0000000000613f87 in GC_mark_thread ()
#4  0x00007f4dbceff0db in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00007f4dbca1890d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6

Thread 6 (Thread 0x7f4dba0f3700 (LWP 7998)):
#0  0x00007f4dbcf030af in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000000000615823 in GC_wait_marker ()
#2  0x000000000060dad5 in GC_help_marker ()
#3  0x0000000000613f87 in GC_mark_thread ()
#4  0x00007f4dbceff0db in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00007f4dbca1890d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6

Thread 5 (Thread 0x7f4db98f2700 (LWP 7999)):
#0  0x00007f4dbcf030af in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000000000615823 in GC_wait_marker ()
#2  0x000000000060dad5 in GC_help_marker ()
#3  0x0000000000613f87 in GC_mark_thread ()
#4  0x00007f4dbceff0db in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00007f4dbca1890d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6

Thread 4 (Thread 0x7f4db90f1700 (LWP 8000)):
#0  0x00007f4dbcf030af in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000000000615823 in GC_wait_marker ()
#2  0x000000000060dad5 in GC_help_marker ()
#3  0x0000000000613f87 in GC_mark_thread ()
#4  0x00007f4dbceff0db in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00007f4dbca1890d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6

Thread 3 (Thread 0x7f4db832b700 (LWP 8001)):
#0  0x00007f4dbc966c1b in sigsuspend () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000000000615941 in GC_suspend_handler ()
#2  <signal handler called>
#3  0x00007f4dbcf0589a in __lll_lock_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#4  0x00007f4dbcf014d7 in _L_lock_913 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00007f4dbcf01300 in pthread_mutex_lock () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#6  0x0000000000615235 in GC_pthread_join ()
#7  0x0000000000592b67 in mono_threads_join_threads ()
#8  0x00000000005ad192 in finalizer_thread ()
#9  0x0000000000590af4 in start_wrapper ()
#10 0x0000000000604906 in inner_start_thread ()
#11 0x0000000000615456 in GC_start_routine ()
#12 0x00007f4dbceff0db in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#13 0x00007f4dbca1890d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6

Thread 2 (Thread 0x7f4da99c0700 (LWP 8004)):
#0  0x00007f4dbcf050f0 in sem_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000000000615ccc in GC_stop_world ()
#2  0x0000000000606b05 in GC_stopped_mark ()
#3  0x0000000000607407 in GC_try_to_collect_inner ()
#4  0x0000000000607626 in GC_try_to_collect ()
#5  0x00000000006076ae in GC_gcollect ()
#6  0x00000000005ac7ac in mono_domain_finalize ()
#7  0x00000000005a6874 in unload_thread_main ()
#8  0x0000000000604906 in inner_start_thread ()
#9  0x0000000000615456 in GC_start_routine ()
#10 0x00007f4dbceff0db in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#11 0x00007f4dbca1890d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6

Thread 1 (Thread 0x7f4dbda2b740 (LWP 7991)):
#0  0x00007f4dbc966c1b in sigsuspend () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000000000615941 in GC_suspend_handler ()
#2  <signal handler called>
#3  0x00007f4dbcf030ad in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#4  0x00000000005df2d3 in _wapi_handle_timedwait_signal_handle ()
#5  0x00000000005f26fb in wapi_WaitForSingleObjectEx ()
#6  0x00000000005a9062 in mono_domain_try_unload ()
#7  0x00000000005a9154 in mono_domain_unload ()
#8  0x00000000401931d2 in ?? ()
#9  0x00007f4daa37d370 in ?? ()
#10 0x00007f4daa37d370 in ?? ()
#11 0x00007f4daa37d370 in ?? ()
#12 0x0000000001f17068 in ?? ()
#13 0x00007f4daa359af0 in ?? ()
#14 0x0000000001abb1d0 in ?? ()
#15 0x0000000040192dd4 in ?? ()
#16 0x00007fff4c7a9fe0 in ?? ()
#17 0x00007fff4c7a9ed0 in ?? ()
#18 0x0000000040192da8 in ?? ()
#19 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Comment: The stack trace you provided is meaningless by itself. You need to show the output from `thread apply all where`.

Comment: @Employed Russian, thanks, I've added the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was seeing hangs and some segfaults in my test automation (both in nunit and my own process) against mono 4.0.3 - which had been fine with 3.12.1 - that resolved once I upgraded to mono 4.0.4.1

I didn't see anything in the release notes for 4.0.4 that looked directly related. But definitely resolved those issues I was having.